# Язык и, задача с массивами (x2)

Tags: c, массивы, исследование

//Создал новый вопрос, потому что слишком много изменил в программе и в самом вопросе.

Задача:
Даны три последовательности X, Y, Z из n действительных чисел ( n < 200). Вычислить величину (а,a) - (b,c), где а обозначает ту из последовательностей X, Y, Z, в которой самый большой минимальный элемент, b и c обозначают две другие последовательности.

Вопрос: Выбираем a (массив с максимальным минимальным элементом) в подпрограмме `float* max_min_el` , а как выбрать b и c?

Code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <locale.h>
 #define n 200
 float min(float *a, int k) {
     float min = a[0];
     for (int i = 1; i < k; ++i)
        if (a[i] < min) min = a[i];
     return min;
 }
 // Определяем минимальный элемент каждого массива
 float* max_min_el(float *X, float *Y, float *Z, int k)
 {
     float ma = min(X, k);
     float mb = min(Y, k);
     float mc = min(Z, k);
     float m = ma;
     float *a = X;
     if (m < mb) 
     {
        a = Y;
        m = mb;
     }
     if (m < mc) 
        a = Z;
     return a;
 }
 // определяем массив с максимальным минимальным элементом
 float scalar(float *a, float *b, int k)
 {
     float s = 0.0;
     for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        s += a[i] * b[i];
     return s;
 }
 // вычисляем скалярное произведение
 float answer(float *X, float *Y, float *Z, int k)
 {
     float * m = max_min_el(X, Y, Z, k);
     if (m == X) return scalar(X, X, k) - scalar(Y, Z, k);
     if (m == Y) return scalar(Y, Y, k) - scalar(X, Z, k);
     return scalar(Z, Z, k) - scalar(Y, X, k);
 }
 // последнее действие: вычитаем (a,a) - (b,c)
 int main() {
     setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
     float X[n], Y[n], Z[n];
     int k;
     float Xmin, Ymin, Zmin;
     printf("введите k \n");
     scanf("%d", &k);
     printf("\n Введите значения массива X:\n");
     for (int i = 0; i<k; i++) {
        printf("X[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%f", &X[i]);
     }
     printf("\n Введите значения массива Y:\n");
     for (int i = 0; i<k; i++) {
        printf("Y[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%f", &Y[i]);
     }
     printf("\n Введите значения массива Z:\n");
     for (int i = 0; i<k; i++) {
        printf("X[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%f", &Z[i]);
     }
    x = answer(X, Y, Z, k);
    printf("\n x = %f", x);
     _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас `max_min_el` возвращает указатель, который совпадает с одним из массивов.

Два несовпадающих массива и будут `b` и `c`.

Да ведь у вас же вот:

```
 float * m = max_min_el(X, Y, Z, k);
 if (m == X) return scalar(X, X, k) - scalar(Y, Z, k);
 if (m == Y) return scalar(Y, Y, k) - scalar(X, Z, k);
 return scalar(Z, Z, k) - scalar(Y, X, k);
```

Если выбран `X` - то он в первом вызове, во втором `Y` и `Z`.
Если выбран `Y` - то он в первом вызове, во втором `X` и `Z`.
Если выбран `Z` - то он в первом вызове, во втором `Y` и `X`.

Answer (score 0):

А в каком виде вы хотели бы их получить?

Например, так вас устроит?

```
 float *b, *c, * a = max_min_el(X, Y, Z, k);
 if (a == X) { b = Y; c = Z; }
 if (a == Y) { b = X; c = Z; }
 if (a == Z) { b = X; c = Y; }
```

Comment: Да вроде и так все нормально, я просто в конце добавил  `x = answer(X, Y, Z, k);
printf("\n x = %f", x);`  Считает верно. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли что то сократить или сделать покрасивее? Саму программу в вопросе исправил.

Comment: А что именно не нравится? Вроде бы как раз покороче... Разве что я бы еще в отдельную функцию вынес заполнение массива, и вызывал ее три раза для разных массивов...

Comment: Все нравится) Спасибо)